# Change array of rows into array of columns in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

Currently, I have an array of rows, but I want an array of columns, so I can plot the data against each other.  Here is some sample code, I get values for the first two columns; however, it is not getting the last column correct.

```
var rows = ["tm","Adata","Bdata",
            0,-0.14,4.781,
            0.003,-0.153,4.781,
            0.006,-0.151,4.831,
            0.008,-0.137,4.831];

var date = new Array();
var A = new Array();
var B = new Array();

// loop through all rows
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
// this line helps to skip empty rows
if (rows[i]) {
    // our columns are separated by comma
    var column = rows[i].split(",");

    // column is array now 
    // first item is date
    date[i] = column[0];
    // second item is value of the second column
    A[i] = column[1];
    // third item is value of the second column
    B[i] = column[3];

}
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. Arrays are created using brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`. With your code, `rows === 4.831`.

Comment: I don't understand why you're splitting anything.  Did you edit this code specifically to post the question?  If so, I think you've removed components that are part of the question.

Comment: I have to re-parse the data because how it parsed originally was row-wise and I cannot call on an entire column when it is like that (or at least, I don't know how to do that).

Comment: @Oriol Non-sense, `new Array()` creates a normal array via its constructor. `[]` is an array literal. It is indeed preferable to use `[]`, but `new Array()` does create an array.

Comment: @IngoBürk I was referring to (simplifying) `var rows = (1,2,3)`, which is equivalent to `var rows; 1; 2; rows = 3;`, so I suggested `var rows = [1,2,3]`. Now I see it was a typo and fixed in an edit.

Comment: @Oriol Alright then. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
B[i] = column[3];
```

To

```
B[i] = column[2];
```

That should get the last column.